# Find which URLs are Listed in Column A and not in Column B via appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have column A under which URLs are listed and column B under which the URLs are listed too. I want to find which URLs are listed in A but not in column B.

[image: Desired Outcome]

Code.gs

So far I was able to do this.

```
function populateColumnC() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var noOfRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,noOfRows,2); 
  sheet.getRange(1,3,1,1).setValue('Listed in A but not in B');
  const dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  //Logger.log(dataValues);


  for (var i =0; i<dataValues.length; i++) {

   Logger.log(dataValues[i])

  }

}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual situation and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this case, the output values are URLs.

```js
function populateColumnC() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var noOfRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, noOfRows, 2);
  const dataValues = dataRange.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => c.getLinkUrl() || ""));
  // Logger.log(dataValues);

  const obj = new Set(dataValues.map(([, b]) => b));
  const res = dataValues.reduce((ar, [a]) => {
    if (!obj.has(a)) {
      ar.push([a]);
    }
    return ar;
  }, [['Listed in A but not in B']]);
  sheet.getRange(1, 3, res.length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, I guess that your expected result is put into column "C".
- Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, if `const dataValues = dataRange.getValues();` returns the URLs, I think that `const dataValues = dataRange.getValues();` can be also used instead of `const dataValues = dataRange.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => c.getLinkUrl() || ""));`.

#### Modified script 2:

In this case, the output values are the rich text including hyperlinks.

```js
function populateColumnC() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var noOfRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, noOfRows, 2);
  const dataValues = dataRange.getRichTextValues();
  const obj = new Set(dataValues.map(([, b]) => b.getLinkUrl()));
  const res = dataValues.reduce((ar, [a]) => {
    const url = a.getLinkUrl();
    if (url && !obj.has(url)) {
      ar.push([a]); // or ar.push([a.copy().setLinkUrl(url).build()]);
    }
    return ar;
  }, [[SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText('Listed in A but not in B').build()]]);
  sheet.getRange(1, 3, res.length).setRichTextValues(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: thanks for the answer. The modified script 2 works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. About `thanks for the answer. The modified script 2 works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Can you explain this part ```  const obj = new Set(dataValues.map(([, b]) => b.getLinkUrl()));```

Comment: @Arif Ahmed About `const obj = new Set(dataValues.map(([, b]) => b.getLinkUrl()));`, the URLs are retrieved from the rich text values of column "B" and put them into Set object. By this, the duplicate values are removed and the values can be also searched. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.